Unable to Save Modifications to GIS Cloud WFS Layer in QGIS?
I am encountering an issue when attempting to save modifications to a WFS layer from GIS Cloud in QGIS. Here are the steps we have taken and the issue encountered:
Verification of Credentials: We have confirmed that our authentication details are correct and that we have the necessary permissions to edit the layer.
Loading the WFS Layer in QGIS: We used the WFS URL https://editor.giscloud.com/wfs/maps/ID_MAP to load the giscloud:Xlayers layer into QGIS.
Modifying Entities: We were able to select and modify entities in QGIS without any issues.
Saving Issue: However, when attempting to save the modifications, we received the following error:
sql
Copier le code
["Could not commit changes to layer giscloud
. ERROR: 1 feature(s) not deleted."
]
Additional Information:
QGIS Version: 3.36.1
WFS Version: max 2.0.0
GIS Cloud Service URL: https://editor.giscloud.com/wfs/maps/ID_MAP
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone have insights on how to resolve this?

I think the issue stems from permission. Although giscloud.com doc says that you can share map as WFS to view, edit but in reality you will have to ask their support for permission. I am not sure if they are using GeoServer or something else, but they will have to allow the permission in the first place, so if you are a premium customer, go ahead ask them.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
